# How can i Increase AllocSpace Size?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I get message on cocsole Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 99519(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 176(3MB) LOS objects, 19% free, 58MB/73MB, paused 3.941ms total 121.614ms. But my activity doesnt have many objects 19% free is very small for what i'm preview in activity.How can i increase that? I used android:largeHeap="true" inside manifest but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should the Android system allocate more memory to your app than it needs?
A memory consumption of 10mb is rather small, so that's good. You don't need `android:largeHeap="true"`, this is used primarily for video and game applications.
As long as your app doesn't suffer from `OutOfMemoryException`s there's nothing you need to do. 
Also, apart from `android:largeHeap="true"`, there's nothing you *can* do. 
It's the OS's job to take care of memory allocation, not yours ;)

Comment: Thank you that helps me a lot.I was just afraid if i'm doing something wrong and i limit my memory.